# Is there anyway to increase the load time of a web page due to image quality?

Tags: png, pageload, image-size, page-load-time

Are there any web tricks to speed up the loading of a web page. I have a few pages where I have images which were created in photoshop, but they are saved as a PNG. The load time is fairly slow of the page due to this, is there anyway to speed up a page load? They are in the region of `1.2/1.5MB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compress the images using an online tool. Although, this may slightly reduce the quality.

I’ve used this site before: https://tinypng.com/

Other than that, I’m not sure if you can “speed up” the load time for a webpage.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was worried about. I wasn't sure if there were any built in dev tools we could use. I'll check out that link :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the size of the file would be a significant advantage.

Additionally converting the asset to webp for Chrome and Firefox, jp2 for Safari and falling back to png would help retain quality while reducing file size.

If the image isn’t in the first viewport you can also try lazy loading the image with something like lazysizes or at the very least the loading attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your website images here
https://www.imghaste.com/pagespeed/

1.2 to 1.5MB for each image is way large. 
You need to adopt a process where you can optimize/shrink images for your website.

If you don't really need the images to be PNG you can always convert them to JPEG.
https://www.imghaste.com/converter